# The Script Task Is Corrupted - SSIS package

Tags: sql-server, ssis, ssis-2012

I opened the SSIS package, and got following errors:

> Validation error: xyz: The Script Task is corrupted.
>
> Validation error: xyz: There were errors during task validation.

I have overall 18 such errors.
Do not have any idea what I should do.
The point is - it is a **productive** package, which means it runs without errors.
Why am I trying to edit it - it is not getting the most recent data.
What I tried by now - I tried to google the error, and to search Stackoverflow's database with keywords 'The Script Task Is Corrupted'. Did not find anything that could help me move forward.

By the way, this package is made long time ago, I do not know with which version of the tool... I have to analyse now why it is not getting the most recent data.

Here is the screenshot of the task flow and errors:
[image]

Here are the scripts the project contains:

[image]

And additionally the folder 'bin' hast the following file 'AuditLogsLoader.dtsx'.

When I open the script (AuditLogsLoader.dtsx) not in BIDS but in Server Data Tools, and click on the script with the error in it, I get to Script Task Editor where I cannot do much, but to click on 'Edit Script'. But If I do that, I get the following error:

[image]

After trying Ray's suggestion, I got the following error:
[image]

Comment: Did you try opening the script? SSIS was introduced only with SQL 2005. So, you have only three major versions to contend with - 2005, 2008/R2 and 2012. Try opening on a machine which has 2005 tools installed

Comment: Thanks for the feedback! I have updated my question with the corresponding files and folders. Since I do not have experience with SSIS, I would appreciate if you could tell me which script I should with which tool open.

Comment: Open the package in BIDS, ignore the errors and double click on any of the script tasks with a error icon on it. Check if the script task actually opens or it throws another error. Sometimes it will just be corrupt metadata which will get automatically fixed when the task is opened

Comment: I did, please see the updated question, and tell me what you think.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

1. Open the Developer Command Prompt for VS2012 as Administrator
2. execute the command cd "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual
   Studio 11.0\Common7\IDE\PrivateAssemblies"
3. execute the command gacutil /if Microsoft.SqlServer.Dts.Design.dll
4. restart Visual Studio

Comment: Hi Raj!
In CMD (which I run as Admin) I excuted the following command: "gacutil /if Microsoft.SqlServer.Dts.Design.dll" and got the error - command not found. See the screenshot please in the updated question.

Comment: Strange. Just type `gacutil` and see if you get a list of switches or the same error. If you still get the error, I think your VS2012 installation is not correct

Comment: it can't find the command... What do you recommend? Reinstall VS0212?